# how to align text inside textField in bottom

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

```
BasicTextField(value = "Country Name",
              onValueChange = {},
              modifier = Modifier
                  .fillMaxWidth()
                  .height(36.dp),
              interactionSource = interactionSource,
              enabled =true,
              singleLine = true,
              textStyle = TextStyle(
                  textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                  fontSize = 15.sp
              ),
              decorationBox = {
              innerTextField ->
   TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
       value = "Country Name",
       innerTextField =  innerTextField,
       enabled = true,
       singleLine = true,
       visualTransformation =VisualTransformation.None,
       interactionSource = interactionSource,
       trailingIcon = {
               Icon(
                   imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowDropDown,
                   contentDescription = null,
                   tint = Green,
                    modifier = Modifier
               )
       },
       colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
           containerColor = Color.Transparent,
           focusedIndicatorColor = Green,
           unfocusedIndicatorColor = Green,
           textColor = Color.Black
       ),
       contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 0.dp)
                  )
          })
Row (horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
   BasicTextField(
       value = countryCode,
       onValueChange = { countryCode = it },
       modifier = Modifier
           .fillMaxWidth(0.25f)
           .height(36.dp)
           ,
       interactionSource = interactionSource,
       enabled =true,
       singleLine = true,
       textStyle = TextStyle(
           textAlign = TextAlign.End,
           fontSize = 15.sp
       ),
       decorationBox = {
               innerTextField ->
   TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
       value = countryCode,
       innerTextField =  innerTextField,
       enabled = true,
       singleLine = true,
       visualTransformation =VisualTransformation.None,
       interactionSource = interactionSource,
               leadingIcon = {
                       Icon(
                           imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                           contentDescription = null,
                           tint = Color.Gray,
                           modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
                       )               
               },
       colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
           containerColor = Color.Transparent,
           focusedIndicatorColor = Green,
           unfocusedIndicatorColor = Green,
           textColor = Color.Black
       ),
       contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
   )
       }
   )
   BasicTextField(
       value = phoneNum,
       onValueChange = { phoneNum = it },
       keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
           imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
           keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone
       ) ,
       modifier = Modifier
           .fillMaxWidth(0.75f)
           .height(36.dp)
           .height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
       interactionSource = interactionSource,
       enabled =true,
       singleLine = true,
       textStyle = TextStyle(
           textAlign = TextAlign.End,
           fontSize = 15.sp
       ),
       decorationBox = {
               innerTextField ->
           TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
               value = phoneNum,
               innerTextField =  innerTextField,
               enabled = true,
               singleLine = true,
               visualTransformation =VisualTransformation.None,
               interactionSource = interactionSource,
               colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                   containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                   focusedIndicatorColor = Green,
                   unfocusedIndicatorColor = Green,
                   textColor = Color.Black
               ),
               contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 8.dp)
           )
       })
}
```

[image]
[image]

I am trying to achieve same result as 1st image(look the text and icon which is at almost bottom of textField) but I am facing problem, I don't know how to align inside text to bottom of textField and leading icon attribute itself has default size which is causing my country code text to be at end of textfield  so is there any way to reduce the size of leading icon attribute(see the below image for default leading icon size)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by updating the decoration box.
Here is the example:

```
Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = countryCode,
            onValueChange = { countryCode = it },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.20f)
                .height(36.dp),
            enabled = true,
            singleLine = true,
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                fontSize = 15.sp
            ),
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        tint = Color.Gray,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
                    )
                }
                TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
                    value = countryCode,
                    innerTextField = innerTextField,
                    enabled = true,
                    singleLine = true,
                    visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                        containerColor = Color.Transparent,
                        focusedIndicatorColor = Green,
                        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Green,
                        focusedTextColor = Color.White
                    ), interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp, 0.dp, 16.dp, 0.dp)
                )
            }
        )
    }
```